# Scala how to group a map and then subgroup and transform values

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

I have an object like this:

```
case class MyObject(x : Int,y : String,...) {
   val buckets = 3
   def bucket = x % buckets // returns a number between 0 and |buckets|
}
```

(x is an arbitrary number)

for example assume "buckets = 3" and we have many objects

```
MyObject(x = 0, y = "Something", ...)
MyObject(x = 1, y = "Something else", ...)
....
...
```

Using "`groupBy`" I collect "`MYObjects`" using the `x % buckets`, so it will be like:

```
val objects : Seq[MyObject] = ...
val groupedObjects : Map[Int: Seq[MyObjects]] = objects.groupBy(obj => x.bucket)
```

now I want to transform each value and also regroup to sublists of the different type

so lets say for each item in group = 1 , I want to nest under an additional layer and store a different calculated value:

so lets say if bucket 0 after the initial grouping looked like:

```
bucket[0] = [obj1,obj2,...,objn]
```

I want to be able to transform bucket "0" to contain another nested grouping:

```
bucket[0] = Map(sub_bucket_0 -> [transformed(objects)...], sub_bucket_1 -> [transformed(object)...),....]
```

meaning that eventually I have a data structure with the type:

```
Map[Int,Map[Sub_bucket_type,Seq[TransformedObject_type]]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `mapValues()` which will modify the Map's value elements to new values and/or types.

```
groupedObjects.mapValues(_.groupBy(/*returns new key type/value*/))
              .mapValues(_.mapValues(_.map(/*transform MyObject elements*/)))
```